# clojure is supposed to be 'code is data' yet I can't add to the end of a list?

Tags: clojure

I have a representation of a matrix in grid.clj file:

```clj
(-> (grid 10 10)
    (toggle 2 3 4 5)
    (off 2 3 4 5)
    (on 2 3 4 5))
```

It's a list of functionts, first one initializes a grid, others modify it.
Clojures' 'code is data' supposed to make it easy for me to modify that representation by adding an instrucion at the **end** of collection. List is an ordered collection right? Order matters. How do I add an instruction to the end of the list then?
Something like this:

```clj
(def grid (read-string (slurp "grid.clj")))
(conj grid '(off 1 2 3 6))
```

Yet I can't add to the end of the list, which is a data structure that is evaluatable as code. How is it 'code as data' if I can't add to the end of the ordered collection that is meant for code (as data)?

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate why this is a surprise to you? Otherwise this is how `conj` works for lists (it adds to the front) - it behaves differently for different data-structures (e.g. vector) but whether the sequence is supposed to be "code" or not it does not care.

Comment: how conj works is not the issue here. Inability to add to an end of an ordered collection is. I use list because it is a collection for code.

Comment: So your question is how to add to the end of a list?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The best way to make this question valuable to you and to other users is to be specific about the problem you're attempting to solve. Not the fact that appending to lists isn't efficient, but the problem you were trying to solve by appending to lists.

Answer (score 8):

Clojure generally does not provide collection operations when they are inefficient for the implementation. Lists are linked lists. Modifying a list is easy at the head and hard at the tail (you have to walk down the list so it's at least a O(n) linear-time operation).

Clojure also provides vectors which are indexed, ordered, sequential data structures. Adding to the end of a vector is better than linear time, so this operation is provided (via `conj`).

Whether this is for "code" or "data" is irrelevant - determine the operations that you need to perform on a collection, and choose the collection type that implements them efficiently. In this case, a vector is your best choice for the container (absent other information).

Comment: Thanks Alex,
Here's what I'm saying:
Clojure claims 'code is data'.
To substantiate that claim it should make it easy to manipulate code(data) with code.
Data structure that is evaluatable is list (the only reason I'm using it) .
List is not easily manipulatabe in clojure.

Clojure is fun because of ease with which you manipulate data. Yet it doesn't apply to code manipulation, because list is a second grade ("weak" Rich Hickey calls it) data structure in it. If, for example, clojure could eval vectors containing expressions - would be much smother experience. Would be code-is-data.

Answer (score -2):

As Alex points out, `conj` behaves differently for lists & vectors.  You can find more information on Clojure functions & data structures in [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).  Every language has its assumptions and "standard" ways of working, so learning this details is important.

If you want, there are a number of helper and convenience functions in [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) that you find useful.  In particular the functions `append` and `->list` from `tupelo.core` can be of use here:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn append-list
  "Adds items to the end of a sequence, always returning a list"
  [list & items]
  (->list (apply append list items)))

(dotest
  (let [grid (read-string
               "(->  (grid 10 10)
                     (toggle 2 3 4 5)
                     (off 2 3 4 5)
                     (on 2 3 4 5))")
        g1   (conj grid '(off 1 2 3 6))
        g2   (append grid '(off 1 2 3 6))
        g2l  (append-list grid '(off 1 2 3 6))
        l3   (append-list [1 2 3] 4 5 6)
        ]
    (is= grid '(-> (grid 10 10)
                 (toggle 2 3 4 5)
                 (off 2 3 4 5)
                 (on 2 3 4 5)))
    (is= g1 '((off 1 2 3 6)
              ->
              (grid 10 10)
              (toggle 2 3 4 5)
              (off 2 3 4 5)
              (on 2 3 4 5)))
```

So `grid` shows the input data and `g1` shows the mistaken result.  We can get the desired placement with `append`, but it always returns a vector result:

```
    (is= g2 '[->
              (grid 10 10)
              (toggle 2 3 4 5)
              (off 2 3 4 5)
              (on 2 3 4 5)
              (off 1 2 3 6)])
```

and we can fix that by coercing the output to a list via `(->list ...)`

```
    (is= g2l '(->
                (grid 10 10)
                (toggle 2 3 4 5)
                (off 2 3 4 5)
                (on 2 3 4 5)
                (off 1 2 3 6)))

    (is= l3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))

    ))
```

The two functions `append` and `->list` are very simple, but I think they help to clarify code that uses them:

```clj
(defn append
  "Given a sequential object (vector or list), add one or more elements to the end."
  [listy & elems]
  (into (vec listy) elems))   

(defn ->list
  "Coerce any sequential argument into a List."
  [arg]
  (apply list arg))
```

These 2 functions are very explicit about what they accomplish. They will always work for any legal input value (i.e. any sequential data structure), and they always return the same type of result (`append` => vector, `->list` => list). Neither is lazy, so there is never a problem of unconsumed input data nor the congestion of unrealized lazy results.

---

You may be interested in the unit tests for `tupelo.core/append`.  They show not only how the `append` is meant to be used, they also show how bulletproof it is:

```clj
(dotest
  (throws? (t/append 1 2))
  (throws? (t/append [1 2]))
  (throws? (t/append nil 3))
  (is= [1 2 3] (t/append [1 2] 3))
  (is= [1 2 3 4] (t/append [1 2] 3 4))
  (is= [1 2 3 4 5] (t/append [1 2] 3 4 5))

  (throws? (t/append '(1 2)))
  (is= [1 2 3] (t/append '(1 2) 3))
  (is= [1 2 3 4] (t/append '(1 2) 3 4))
  (is= [1 2 3 4 5] (t/append '(1 2) 3 4 5))

  (throws? (t/append {:a 1} 99))
  (throws? (t/append {:a 1} {:b 2}))
  (throws? (t/append #{:a 1} 99))
  (throws? (t/append #{:a 1} #{99}))

  (testing "old conjv tests"
    (is= [2] (t/append [] 2))
    (is= [2] (t/append '() 2))
    (is= [2 3] (t/append [] 2 3))
    (is= [2 3] (t/append '() 2 3))

    (is= [1 2 3] (t/append [1] 2 3))
    (is= [1 2 3] (t/append '(1) 2 3))
    (is= [1 2 3] (t/append [1 2] 3))
    (is= [1 2 3] (t/append '(1 2) 3))

    (is= [1 2 3 4] (t/append [1 2] 3 4))
    (is= [1 2 3 4] (t/append '(1 2) 3 4))
    (is= [1 2 3 4] (t/append [1] 2 3 4))
    (is= [1 2 3 4] (t/append '(1) 2 3 4))

    (is= [[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]] (t/append [[1 2] [3 4]] [5 6]))

    (is= [0 1 2 3 4 5] (t/append (range 4) 4 5))
    (is= [0 1 2 3 4 5] (apply t/append [0] (range 1 6)))))
```